# How to read a query from a resource with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, repository

Here is my repository:

```
public interface MyObjectRepository extends CrudRepository<MyObject, Long> {

    @Query("<a-complex-query>")
    List<MyObject> doBusinessSpecificComplexQuery();

}
```

I can type directly my complex query in the `@Query` annotation but the code loose its readability.

I would like to do something like below instead:

```
public interface MyObjectRepository extends CrudRepository<MyObject, Long> {

    @Query(load("classpath:my-complex-query.sql"))
    List<MyObject> doBusinessSpecificComplexQuery();

}
```

This won't work since `@Query` value parameter expects a constant value.

How can I read my complex query from a resource ?

Comment: you can also check https://github.com/VEINHORN/spring-data-sqlfile library if you want load SQL queries from resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JPA Named Query. You need to put the query in the orm.xml file like this:

```
 <named-query name="User.findByLastname">
    <query>select u from User u where u.lastname = ?1</query>
 </named-query>
```

For example and then you just need to declare the method findByLastname in your repository class:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  List<User> findByLastname(String lastname);   
}
```

You can see the documentation in [Spring Data Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.named-queries) or for 2023 version of dependency have a look at [Spring Data JPA 3.0.3 Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/3.0.3/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and even simpler !